# Apache POI support for "Sheet views"

Tags: java, excel, view, apache-poi, office365

Excel on-line (Office365) has the nice feature to define "Sheet views". With this you can share views on an Excel sheet/workbook. I would like to be able to create these using Apache-POI as I generate some an Excel file every day using Apache-POI. Is this currently possible or is it a Office365-only feature of Excel that is not actually stored in the Excel-file?

Edit: add screenshot of where the "Sheet views" are found in Excel-Office-365.
[image: Where the Sheet views are found in Excel]